# Is there a way to attach a dynamic image to a tweet?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, tweets

I've got functionality on my website to share to twitter. It's just a simple Twitter Intent with some custom text. I'd now like to share an image with this text, not a link to the image, but the image itself like how they're shown in Twitter Cards. I'm at a loss of how to achieve this though.

I've got a web app that changes the data shown based on filters that the user engages. When they click the "share" button, I use PHP GD to generate an image using the current data shown. This image is saved on the server and the url is passed back to the javascript via ajax. Now I would like to open a "twitter share" dialog with my pre-filled text and this image. I have discovered that this is not possible with twitter intents because they don't allow images, only image urls (because actual images shown in tweets are pic.twitter.com images).

So I'm looking at Cards but it seems as though Cards are static. I was wondering if it's possible to make the card metadata dynamic by having a php file which has a hash (e.g. www.example.com/tweet.php?esd87fsduh) that is used to dynamically populate the twitter card meta tags? Or would this not work because it takes a long time for twitters bots to crawl the website again?

I basically want the simple functionality that the user clicks "tweet" and they are presented with the Twitter dialog showing dynamic text and the image based on the data filters they'd applied. Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No. Twitter caches images based upon the tags and refreshes the caches only every 7 days: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting#caching.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply. Does that mean I can only get close to this feature by pre-filling the text of the tweet with a url to the generated image?